# Java matrix contains ArrayList elements

Tags: java, matrix, arraylist

I am writing a tictactoe game, I have 1 `ArrayList<String> OFields`(it's containing fields that O is owning like TOP_LEFT, CENTRE_RIGHT etc) and a

```
String[][] winComb={{"TOP_LEFT","TOP_CENTRE","TOP_RIGHT"}, {"CENTRE_LEFT","CENTRE_CENTRE","CENTRE_RIGHT"},
                    {"BOT_LEFT","BOT_CENTRE","BOT_RIGHT"}, {"TOP_LEFT","CENTRE_LEFT","BOT_LEFT"}, 
                    {"TOP_CENTRE","CENTRE_CENTRE","BOT_CENTRE"}, {"TOP_RIGHT","CENTRE_RIGHT","BOT_RIGHT"},
                    {"TOP_LEFT","CENTRE_CENTRE","BOT_RIGHT"}, {"TOP_RIGHT","CENTRE_CENTRE","BOT_LEFT"}};
```

I want to check, that OFields's elements contains winComb[1..8]

```
if(OFields.contains((winComb[0][0])) && OFields.contains(winComb[0][1]) && OFields.contains(winComb[0][2])){
                                        System.out.println("win");
                                    }
```

That's what i have, it's working for the first `winComb` element but it would be really messy if i write like this. How can i check that all `OFields` element is in winComb matrix?

Comment: Well, using strings and arrays of strings to model the tictactoe board ... seems to be suboptimal. I would suggest to rather spend some time to think up a better "model"; compared to spend time on using this model and make it do what you want it to do.

Comment: They are just containers, im using swing, but i have to store the fields that was used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`List#containsAll()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-):

```
static boolean win(List<String> oFields) {
    for (String[] positions : WIN_COMB) {
        if (oFields.containsAll(Arrays.asList(positions)))
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

But sincerely saying, I agree with [@Jägermeister](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2542565/j%C3%A4germeister) that you should chose more appropriate class model for that.